# SAS regression plot errors

Tags: error-handling, sas, regression

I use `proc reg` to model regression and plot the results. However, I got the error below. Is there any way to solve it?

```
ods graphics on;

proc reg data = Work.Cmds PLOTS(MAXPOINTS=NONE);
model Investment = Size Growth_New Leverage complex Deficit pc_income_NEW 
Density/hcc adjrsq ;
output out=CMDSreg r = AbnInvestment; run;

ERROR: Java virtual machine exception. java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: GC overhead limit exceeded.
ERROR: Java virtual machine exception. java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: GC overhead limit exceeded.
NOTE: The SAS System stopped processing this step because of errors.
WARNING: The data set WORK.CMDSREG may be incomplete.  When this step was stopped there were 0 observations and 0 variables.
WARNING: Data set WORK.CMDSREG was not replaced because this step was stopped.
NOTE: PROCEDURE REG used (Total process time):
  real time           1:05.39
  cpu time            13.48 seconds

quit;
ods graphics off;
```

I browsed the website [here](http://support.sas.com/kb/55/533.html) but still don't understand.

Note:
The data set WORK.CMDS has 587831 observations and 142 variables.
[image]

Comment: Can you show work.cmds, or reproduce the error with a sample data set ?

Comment: @Richard There are many variables in the data. But I provide basic descriptive statistics for the variables used in models

Comment: Increase your MEMSIZE option in your config file.

Comment: @Reeza I use`proc options MEMSIZE=MAX; run;` but get error. Can you help me?

Comment: See using a smaller about of data will work.  data = Work.Cmds(obs=500).

Comment: Memory has to be specified when SAS is started.  That's why @Reeza mentioned CONFIG.